# How to convert string year-dayofyear-milliseconds to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

In a pandas DataFrame I have weird datetime format like so:

```
0    201913907050435
1    201913908520126
2    201914004163647
3    201914019315651
4    201914019320917
Name: DATETIME, dtype: object
```

What I know is, that it's Year followed by day of the year. I guess the number after that is the time in milliseconds or nanoseconds.

I want to transform the type to a pandas datetime object. So far I have:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.DATETIME, format='%Y%j%f')
```

which gives me:

```
0   2019-05-19 00:00:00.070504350
1   2019-05-19 00:00:00.085201260
2   2019-05-20 00:00:00.041636470
3   2019-05-20 00:00:00.193156510
4   2019-05-20 00:00:00.193209170
Name: DATETIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The problem is that HH:MM:SS is always 0 and not filled in correctly. What datetime code do I need instead of %f that can represent milliseconds (or whatever this number is)?

I could not find it in this [table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
### try this
print(pd.to_datetime('201913907050435', format="%Y%j%H%M%S%f"))
##output:
2019-05-19 07:05:04.350000
```

Comment: If you would have read the question carefully you would have seen that it's day-of-year (code %j) at second place. But with your answer I think I got to the correct solution. Please accept my edits then I will accept your answer.

Comment: i have accepted your edit. I missed  little part. Thnx for edit